# Substitute placeholders in template

Tags: bash, text-processing, configuration, replace, variable-substitution

Say I have a shell configuration file `config` like this:

```
HOST=localhost
PORT=8080
```

Now I have a template `template` like this:

```
The host is <%= @HOST %>
The port is <%= @PORT %>
```

How do I substitute placeholders in `template` with values in `config` file?

I can certainly do it like this:

```
$ . config
$ sed -e "s/<%= @HOST %>/$HOST/" \
> -e "s/<%= @PORT %>/$PORT/" < template
The host is localhost
The port is 8080
```

But if there are many config values this becomes too cumbersome. How would I do this in more generic way? I would like to iterate over each placeholder and substitute it with a real value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
eval "cat << __end_of_template__
$(sed 's/[\$`]/\\&/g;s/<%= @\([^ ]*\) %>/${\1}/g' < template)
__end_of_template__"
```

That is, have sed replace all the `<%= @xxx %>` with `${xxx}` after having escaped all the `$`, `\` and `` ` `` characters and let the shell do the expansion.

Or if you can't guarantee that `template` will not contain a `__end_of_template__` line:

```
eval "cut -c2- << x
$(sed 's/[\$`]/\\&/g;s/<%= @\([^ ]*\) %>/${\1}/g;s/^/y/' < template)
x"
```

Comment: +1 really nicely done. Took me a bit to figure out what the later version does. To state the obvious. It uses a HEREDOC where the delimiter is `x` and each line is preprended with an `y` as to prevent a premature stop of the HEREDOC by an line only containing `x`. ingenious :)

Answer (score 4):

An `awk` way:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{v[$1]=$2;next};{for(p in v)gsub("<%= @"p" %>",v[p])};1' config template
```

**Updated** according to [Stephane Chazelas' comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/substitute-placeholders-in-template/57740#comment79633_57740) to allow “=” signs in the values:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{v[$1]=substr($0,length($1)+2);next};{for(p in v)gsub("<%= @"p" %>",v[p])};1' config template
```

Comment: Note that that assumes that the value of the parameters don't contain "=" characters or the name of another parameter (like `FOO="<%= @BAR %>"`)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mustache(1)](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.1.html) to replace a bunch of template variables:

```
$ { echo ---; sed 's/=/: /' config; echo --- } \
  | mustache - <(sed -e 's/<%= @/{{/g' -e 's/%>/}}/g' template)
```

The first element of the pipe translates your configuration assignments into YAML syntax that is understood my mustache. The second `sed` command replaces the `<%= @VAR %>` style variable references into mustache `{{ VAR }}` ones.

On Fedora, `mustache` is part of the `rubygem-mustache` package.

Alternatively, you can use [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) (provided by the `gettext` package), e.g.:

```
$ ( export $(cat config) ; sed -e 's/<%= @\([^%]*\) %>/${\1}/g' template 
  | envsubst )
```

Requires that your variable assignments are also valid in the shell.

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
#!/bin/sh

. config

while read line
do
        eval echo $(echo $line | sed "s/\([^<]*\)<%= @\([^ ]*\) %>/\1 \$\2/")
done < template
```

Results:

```
The host is localhost
The port is 8080
```

Using `sed`, we extract the characters till '<' and form a group(`\1`), and extract the placeholder and form another group(`\2`). This is substituted with the 1st group and then the dollar symbol followed by 2nd group. Just by using the `eval` command, the variable can be evaluated and gets expanded.

Comment: Lines containing shell special characters will be seriously mangled and may cause your script to execute arbitrary code. If the input comes from a non-trusted source, this is a glaring security hole. You need to do some serious quoting and escaping to make this work. (See [Stephane Chazelas's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/substitute-placeholders-in-template/57742#57742) for an example of how to do it right.)