# How to process sed substitution before replacing

Tags: sed

Let's say I have this text: `My name is #1#!`.

I want to replace the `#1#` with something that depends on the contents between the `#`, like:

```
if [ $thing_between_hash -eq 1 ]; then
  subs=John
else
  subs=Mary
fi
```

Then the output would be:

`My name is John!`

Can I do it with a single `sed` substitution? How?

Comment: If your substitution needs get much more complicated, see templating solutions, such as [mustache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350743/117549)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a sed that supports `-r`:

```
sed -r -e 's/#1#/John/g; s/#[^#]+#/Mary/g' <<< 'My name is #1#, not #5#!'
```

otherwise:

```
sed    -e 's/#1#/John/g; s/#[^#][^#]*#/Mary/g' <<< 'My name is #1#, not #5#!'
```

Comment: Instead of `-r` suggest using equivalent `-E` since, per the man page, "the -E option has been supported for years by GNU sed, and is now included in POSIX."

Comment: I failed to find `-E` in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ but will look again when I get back to a computer.  Do you have a more direct reference for it?

Comment: Breadcrumb: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310446/117549

Comment: You won't find it in the current documentation. It will be included in the [next posix issue](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528)

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
something='My name is #1#!'
subs="John"

mod="${something/\#1\#/$subs}"

echo "$mod"
```

Output:

```
My name is John!
```

Comment: What about Mary?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I'm sure he'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

can do so as :

```
 [root@h2g2w ~]# subs=john
 [root@h2g2w ~]# echo may name is 1 | sed
> 's/1/'$subs'/' 
  may name is john 
 [root@h2g2w ~]#
```

Comment: What you've written is syntactically invalid. If it has been mangled by your formatting, please fix that. And some explanation of what you're doing and how it can help the OP would make this a useful answer.

Comment: It also doesn’t anchor the replacements inside hash marks.

Comment: echo "may name is #1#" | sed 's/#1#/'$subs'/'
   may name is john
this just absolutly works  it is the one way to do so & proved as a really done thing...copy/pasting of solution tested :)

Comment: But what about “My name is #1#, and I’m #1!”

Comment: this is not the user question , and  in this cas this just works without confusion until I use the one good #1# mark that can't be confused with #1! so sed exit the good sentance with one & only one subsitution

Comment: It is, actually: `I want to replace the #1#` ...